# Show that $\mathcal{O}_k/(m)$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ be its ring of integers. It is easy to show that there is some nonzero rational integer $m$ in a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. Now, I know that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $n=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$.

I am now having trouble understanding why $\mathcal{O}_K/(m)$ is finite with size $m^n$. I can't really see why $(m)$ would be full rank here, and I think I'm missing something kind of obvious.

Comment: If $x_1, …, x_n$ is an $ℤ$-basis of $\mathcal O_K$, then $mx_1, …, mx_n$ is $ℤ$-linearly independent in $(m)$ (and so it’s a basis furthermore, since $m = m·1 = m·(a_1x_1 + … + a_nx_n)$ for some $a_1, …, a_n ∈ ℤ$).

Comment: If $\mathcal{O}_K \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ then $m \mathcal{O}_K \cong m \mathbb{Z}^n$. Work this out very explicitly in examples like the Gaussian integers.

Answer (score 1):

Question: "I am now having trouble understanding why OK/(m) is finite with size mn. I can't really see why (m) would be full rank here, and I think I'm missing something kind of obvious."

Answer: Any non-zero prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ "restricts" to a non-zero prime ideal  $(p)= \mathfrak{p}\cap \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, since the intersection may be defined as the inverse image under the canonical map of rings $i: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_K$. There is a canonical decomposition of the extended ideal

D1. $(p)\mathcal{O}_K =\mathfrak{p}_1^{l_1} \cdots \mathfrak{p}_i^{l_i}\mathcal{O}_K$

where the ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$ are non-zero prime ideals, and an isomorphism

D2. $\mathcal{O}_K/(p)\mathcal{O}_K \cong \oplus_j \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_j^{l_j}.$

The rings $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_j^{l_j}$ are Artinian local rings for all $j$.
Your original prime ideal satisfies $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}_j$ for some $j$ and this gives rise to a finite extension of finite fields

D3. $\mathbb{F}_p:=\mathbb{Z}/(p)\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$

and from this it follows $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}\cong \mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ for some integer $r \geq 1$. Hence you can choose your integer $m$ to equal a non-zero prime $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, by definition, $(m)=m \mathcal{O}_K$. So you want to show that $\mathcal{O}_K/m\mathcal{O}_K$ is finite. Now, the following is not that hard to prove:

"If $G$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $G/mG$ is the direct sum of $n$ cyclic groups each of order $m$."

Applying this with $G=\mathcal{O}_K$ yields $$ \mathcal{O}_K /m\mathcal{O}_K \cong \underbrace{ (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \oplus \dots \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) }_{\text{$n$ times}}  .$$ Therefore, $\vert \mathcal{O}_K /m\mathcal{O}_K \vert = m^n$.